# Sony WH-1000XM3 headset defaults to SBC codec despite forcing aptX codec

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I am having a Bluetooth headset that supports [AAC and aptX](https://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/wh1000xm3/v1/en/contents/TP0001703175.html).

However, my macOS defaults to SBC codec that causes low-quality audio for music.

[image]

I know the trick how to force AAC / aptX with Bluetooth Utilities Xcode Additional Tools and I have done this.

[image: -]

Even after doing this and restarting the computer, I am still getting SBC as the codec as in the screenshot above.

What others settings I could poke to force the headset to play music nicely?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm having a somewhat similar [issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409629/why-do-my-sony-wh-1000xm3-wireless-headphones-appear-to-have-two-different-volum) with volume, not the codec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Sony Headset app for your mobile ([iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1168502924) or [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sony.songpal.mdr)). They have settings to remotely configure the headphones.

Turn on the setting to prefer the sound quality: *Priority on Sound Quality*.

Now you get aptX:

[image]

[image]