# Why do my Sony WH-1000XM3 wireless headphones appear to have two different volume profiles when using with my Mac?

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, headphones, sound-volume

Note: This is **not an SBC issue** and both the Spotify app and Finder app can exhibit this problem.

Sometimes when I connect my Sony WH-1000XM3 bluetooth headphones to my Mac they are fairly quiet at maximum volume. When I change volume right after the connection is made I sometimes see the volume suddenly jump to what appears to be the volume remembered by another "profile". I'm usually able to reproduce this by turning the headphones off and back on again. I did some research and learned about the different bluetooth profiles and codecs that the headphones support. Based on that I initially thought that what was happening was the headphones were connecting using HSP or HFP instead of AVRCP or A2DP. This is not the case as I have confirmed that even when connected using the "low volume profile" the codec being used is AAC, which is not supported by HSP or HFP.
The only "fix" I've found is disconnecting and reconnecting the headphones. That always seems to put them into the "normal volume profile". If I then switch them off and back on they will most of the time reconnect in the "low volume profile".
Anyone know what is going on, and how to properly fix it?
I'm on an early 2015 13-inch Retina MacBook Pro running macOS 10.15.7.

Comment: @bmike I've seen the behaviour described above in Finder and Spotify. No app switch is necessary. I can be in Finder and I'll be playing with the volume keys (toggling one up, one down, to see the volume HUD) and sometimes a short time after the headphones connect the volume will jump to whatever it was set to in the other "profile". Does that make sense? Perhaps I should try to create a screen recording of this…it's fairly easy to reproduce.

Comment: @bmike, I see you edited my note. I find that a little misleading, because the issue is not limited to a specific app. Those are just the two apps that are most likely to be active when I connect my headphones, actually Chrome too. The app seems to be totally irrelevant.

Comment: Just trying to help - edits are logged so people can see who did what. Feel free to refine, rollback, improve as needed. Thanks for letting me know I missed the mark @bemk (p.s. I’m your only fan it appears, no one else has even given you a +1 here :(

Comment: I have the same issue on a mid-2014 MBP running Mojave 10.14.6. Don't know of any fix or root cause, unfortunately.